# Average and SD for not paired and different number replicates

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

```
   mydf <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                       id    col1     col2     col3     col4
                       fow1  1        8        5        10
                       fow1  3        7        4        20
                       fow1  5        6        3        40
                       fow1  1        8        5        10
                       fow1  3        7        4        20
                       fow1  5        6        3        40
                       aow2  10       1        2        5
                       aow2  10       1        2        5
                       aow2  10       1        2        5

                     ")
```

I want to calculate the average ratio and SD for aow2/fow1, I can not calculate it for each single replicate because they are not paired and different number.
I could calculate average and SD for each column fow1 and aow but how can I calculate the aow2/fow1 average and SD? What scripts should I use?

Comment: Your question asks to make an estimate from data you don't have: without any pairing, you have  *no* specific information about the ratios `aos2/fow1`!  If the different rows are for different subjects, you have no information whatsoever about the ratios.  If they are for the same set of subjects, but you don't have any subject identifiers, then you can obtain bounds for the statistics by considering all possible ways of pairing them, but such bounds are typically of little use.

Comment: Different rows are indeed different subjects. Of course I could take the mean for `aos2`\ `fow1`, but what can I take as as SD?

Comment: Re "of course": there is no necessary relationship between the mean of the ratio and the ratio of the means.  You can only obtain (very wide) bounds for one in terms of the other.  Estimating the SD is even more uncertain.

Comment: I meant I can take the average of each `aos2` and `aos2` after take the ratio, `aos2_average\ fow12_average`. But still I don'tknow how to calculate the SD

Comment: Right: that would be the *ratio of the averages.*  But it could be far from the "average ratio" requested in your question.